# How I am supposed to send product data to stripe for web hooks?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

How I can add data to craft commerce stripe product while ordering, Actually I have used stripe webhooks so need meta data to identify the products

Comment: Commerce 2 or 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

If this is Commerce 2, you're probably looking for the [buildGatewayRequest](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe/blob/master/src/gateways/Gateway.php#L81) event. From the transaction property set on that event, you should be able to get the Order and all the products.